# attributeerror: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'. How do fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to make automated login to router web GUI, but if I use
input_tags.send_keys("PASSWORD"), then I get error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'.

Here is my code example

```
#imports
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#login
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://ROUTER_IP')
password = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "login_password")
password.send_keys("PASSWORD")
```

Here is webpage inspect picture:

[webpage inspect picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p3OC.png)

Here is my output:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

I tried to Google this, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_elements` returns you a list of elements. If you're certain there's only a single element that satisfiers your criterion, you can just use:

```py
password = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "login_password")[0]
```

Comment: OK. I tried it, but now is new error. Now it says that: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Taurire That means there is no element with the specified id

Comment: I added webpage inspect picture, where is "login_password" located.

Comment: Still, your driver does not see one, and returns you an empty list. I don't have much experience with selenium specifically, so I can't tell you what can cause that straight away

Comment: Okey. Still thanks for fast reply and little bit help. Maybe someone else can help me more, but until then I'll make little bit research about that error. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case there is only 1 element on that page having `id = 'login_password'` all you need to make your code working is to change from `find_elements` to `find_element`.
Try this code:

```py
#imports
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#login
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://ROUTER_IP')
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "login_password")
password.send_keys("PASSWORD")
```

Comment: This will make a lot of errors :(. I think somehow it still don't find id="login_password".

Comment: According to what you shared - the only error is what you made by using `find_elements` instead of `find_element`, but I actually have no idea what is going on at your side